# Hadoop Map Reduce - Read HDFS File - FileAlreadyExists error

Tags: file, hadoop

I am new to Hadoop. I am trying to read an existing file on HDFS using the below code. The configuration seem file and the file path is correct as well.  -

```
public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

    private static Text f1, f2, hdfsfilepath;
    private static HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> friendsData = new HashMap<>();

    public void setup(Context context) throws IOException {
      Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
      Path path = new Path("hdfs://cshadoop1" + conf.get("hdfsfilepath"));
      FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(path.toUri(), conf);
      if (fs.exists(path)) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(fs.open(path)));
        String line;
        line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
          StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
          String friend = str.nextToken();
          ArrayList<String> friendDetails = new ArrayList<>();
          while (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
            friendDetails.add(str.nextToken());
          }
          friendsData.put(friend, friendDetails);
        }
      }
    }

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      for (String k : friendsData.keySet()) {
        context.write(new Text(k), new Text(friendsData.get(k).toString()));
      }
    }
  }
```

I am getting the below exception when I run the code -

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory hdfs://cshadoop1/socNetData/userdata/userdata.txt already exists
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(FileOutputFormat.java:146)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.checkSpecs(JobSubmitter.java:458)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:343)
```

I am just trying to read an existing file. Any ideas what I am missing here? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Exception tells you that your **output** directory already exists but it should not. Delete it or change its name.

Moreover the name of your output directory 'userdata.txt' looks like the name of a file. So check you are not mistaken in your input/output directories.